# Automatic switching between Python 2 and Python 3 using the shebang using Python Anaconda and PEP 397 (Python launcher for Windows)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, shebang

Can you use the "[PEP 397: Python launcher for Windows](http://blog.python.org/2011/07/python-launcher-for-windows_11.html)" when using [Python Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) and have created a Python 3 environment. Specifically, I would like to run scripts and the launcher automatically looks for a Unix-style #! (shebang) line in the code and switches between Python 2 and Python 3 automatically.

I believe the PEP 397 was incorporated in Python 3.3 and Anaconda includes Python 3.4 (Sep 2014) and so should have this somewhere but I cant find it.